# what's the purpose of IInterceptionBehaviour's GetRequiredInterfaces?

Tags: c#, unity-container, aop, interceptor

I implemented an InterceptionBehaviour (unity) to log stuff before and after the method calls. I am passing/injecting an ILogger interface in the constructor of my behavior. My question is do I need to have the ILogger interface returned by GetRequiredInterfaces or not? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I need to have the ILogger interface returned by GetRequiredInterfaces or not?

No you don't. Simply inject `ILogger` into the constructor of the interception behavior class and make sure that you register `ILogger` with the container.

> why?

Interception works by creating a proxy class that wraps the intercepted object. You can use `GetRequiredInterfaces` to make such proxy class implement additional interfaces without the (original) target object actually implementing these interfaces. What you are trying to do however, is not related to such scenario.